# Flutter: How to limit get images in flutter "ListView.builder()"?

Tags: flutter

i get images data from web server but, total data is 200+ MB, if I load it at once, the app will crash. how to limit get photos, maybe take every 5 photos.

i'm use ListView.builder() - FLutter
and i try use cache image library

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: dataJSON == null ? 0 : dataJSON.length,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    Container(
      height: 100.0,
      width: 70.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(5)
        ),
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          image: new CachedNetworkImageProvider(dataJSON[i]['photo'])
        ),
      ),
    ),
  },
)
```

when I scroll, maybe 20 photos and then crash, the app is exit

what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NotificationListener` to increase the length of your `ListView` when the user reaches its end, this way only photos to be displayed will be fetched from the network :

```
     int list_length ;


     @override
     void initState() {
       list_length = dataJSON.length == null ? 0 : 5 ;
       super.initState();
     }

     NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
         onNotification: (scrollNotification){
              if(scrollNotification.metrics.pixels == scrollNotification.metrics.maxScrollExtent){
                 setState(() {
                      list_length = list_length + 10 <= dataJSON.length ? list_length += 10 : dataJSON.length ;
                    });
              }
         },
      child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list_length,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        Container(
          height: 100.0,
          width: 70.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(5)
            ),
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              image: new CachedNetworkImageProvider(dataJSON[i]['photo'])
            ),
          ),
        ),
      },
    )
```

Comment: When I scroll down, done, it doesn't crash, and I scrolled up the images its load again. how i maintain images?

Comment: you can use `addAutomaticKeepAlives: true` option, but beware of its effect on your memory after creating many items.

Comment: How does Instagram work? when scroll down and scroll up, the image remains intact? does that take up a lot of memory?

Comment: I don't know about its specific design, but I pointed out the memory issue because `ListView` by default destroys out-of-view widgets as a memory management technique, and by overriding this setting you have to actively manage your widgets' lifecycle. Probably other users have faced a similar situation and asked about it somewhere here. And if not, you can ask about it.

Comment: Not at all ... :)